# Ubuntu Phone no data network after upgrade OTA-12

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

My BQ Aquaris 4.5, after upgrade to OTA-12, don't detect SIM in mobile data configurations (System > Cellular).

It's working for all other things (call, send SMS, etc).

Can I downgrade to OTA-11?

Thanks.

Comment: In System Settings > Mobile is Cellular data on?  Do you just have 1 SIM?  Is your phone the one with 4G?

Comment: I have 2 SIM. Yes the first is 4G, and it isn't recognized.

Comment: Have you tried the basics like reboot, taking the sim oout and putting it back in or even swaping the sims ovee to see it you get data recogniswd in the other slot? I have been having lots of issuea with mobile data and my E5 but all was ok after the upgrade. I would go as far as saying slightly better. One thing that works for me is turning flight mode on and then off again.

Comment: Yes, I tried all, swap SIM slot, reboot, flight mode.

Comment: The next thig may be to reset tye phone and see how that goes.

Comment: If you swipe down from the Network indicator, is Cellular data enabled?  If not, it could be this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1607079 which will be fixed by OTA13

Comment: Yes, Cellular data is enabled.

Comment: You're probably seeing this bug: http://pad.lv/1607079. It should be fixed with the upcoming OTA-13 update.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing!

I've resolved upgrading to latest rc-preposed release.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is [known](http://pad.lv/1607079) and resolved but it will release in next OTA-13.

If is not possible to wait, you may [upgrade to the latest rc-proposed](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/#upgrade-ubuntu) release.

Comment: Hopefully it will be resolved in the next releasr, which i should imagine will be along soon. I can only hope that this will resolve the overall mobile data connectivity issue that i am also facing on my E5.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that others know that it has an accepted answer. Accepting your own answer is totally fine and is encouraged